# Bootstrap 3: Setting custom container sizes based on page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking to have a couple of pages that are not the default container size.
For example, say my default is 1170px (Bootstraps default). Then say I want a container that is about 8 columns wide, based on the default 1170px width, which is 780px.

I know the first thought for many will be to maintain the 1170px container and then just use 8 columns, with an offset of 2, but that does not get the desired results I would like. As it will cause the page to resize at the default 1170px media query settings. Thus I want a new container to be set at 875px.

My first thought is to do something like this in SASS:

```
@for $i from 6 through 11 {
  .layout-size-#{$i}{
    .main-cont{
      $container-width: (0.083333 * $i) * 1170px; // Single column width in percentage times # of columns, multiplied by max container width.
      width: ceil($container-width);
    }
  }
}
```

I could then do something similar within various media queries to modify as needed for each screen size. Thoughts? Is there a better method?

Comment: You know you have col-md. col-sm, etc. To control the floating of your columns, right?

Comment: Yes, but my issue isn't with positioning columns. It's with setting when the container decides to resize. I don't want to container to resize before it has to. So if I have a page set to 10 columns, it shouldn't be resizing to a smaller size when the window hits the default 12 column width. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I believe I've got this working now. I was not entirely right in my initial question. What I have come up with is this:

```
@for $i from 6 through 10 {
  $container-width: ceil((0.083333 * $i) * 1170px); // Single column width in percentage times # of columns, multiplied by max container width.
  @media (min-width: ($container-width + $grid-gutter-width)) {
    .layout-size-#{$i}{
      .main-cont{
        width: $container-width;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is set up a number of media queries set at the width of each possible container (plus gutter). So if we wanted a container that matches the width of 6 columns (with base 1170px for 12 col) it would be 585px. Then we setup a class to set the container to that width. My class "layout-size-6" is assumed to be set on the body element. The class "main-cont" is assumed to be on the same element as "container" class.

Ultimately, this allows the viewport to shrink as small as the container before it resizes to the default widths setup by Bootstrap's media queries.

The resulting CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 615px) {
  .layout-size-6 .main-cont {
    width: 585px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 713px) {
  .layout-size-7 .main-cont {
    width: 683px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 810px) {
  .layout-size-8 .main-cont {
    width: 780px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 908px) {
  .layout-size-9 .main-cont {
    width: 878px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1005px) {
  .layout-size-10 .main-cont {
    width: 975px;
  }
}
```

You could, of course, modify the FOR statement for more or less container sizes.